# Gdalwarp results in raster of zero's

Tags: raster, gdal, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to create a global raster from different 5*5 degree tiles. Herefore, I converting my label + image file to a geotiff with gdal_translate. Afterwards I use gdalwarp to reproject the data. This works fine for all tiles between 0 and 180 degrees longitude but results in a raster with only zeros for all between -180 till 0 degrees longitude.

The data is CRISM summary product data from Mars.

Input Proj4-file:

```py
PROJCS["EQUIRECTANGULAR_MARS",GEOGCS["GCS_MARS",DATUM["D_MARS",SPHEROID["MARS_localRadius",3396000.0,0.0]],PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Equidistant_Cylindrical"],PARAMETER["false_easting",0.0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0.0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",327.5],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",42.5],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Output Proj4-file:

```py
GEOGCS["GCS_Mars_2000",DATUM["D_Mars_2000",SPHEROID["Mars_2000_IAU_IAG",3396190.0,169.8944472236118]],PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["Esri",104905]]
```

Does anyone have an idea why the data in my raster only consists of zero's after the described steps? (see code below)

```py
gdal_translate -a_nodata 65535 
/home/kampsom/Documents/CRISM/Raw_data/$filename_lbl 
/home/kampsom/Documents/CRISM/Converted/$filename_tif

gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs 
/home/kampsom/Documents/CRISM/Converted/Mars_2000.prj 
/home/kampsom/Documents/CRISM/Converted/$filename_tif 
/home/kampsom/Documents/CRISM/Converted/$filename_tif_repr
```